# ng-change triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I bumped into a mystery I cannot get my head around. I have a directive in Angular that creates a -element. On that I have a value-attribute that acts as my model, but in order to use an ngChange I have to have the ng-model in place as well. However, this construction leads me to have an to me odd behaviour: it fires the ngChange on all directives I use in my ng-repeat.

Best to be seen in a quick test:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SXpytBCPPHd1AkwIyMf6?p=preview

```
<dropdown-field 
    label="{{ comment.title }}" 
    options="vm.options"
    ng-model="comment.target.id"
    ng-change="vm.changeFn(comment)"
></dropdown-field>
```

Can someone please guide me towards a resolution on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is behaving like that because when you bind directive with HTML element it will occur for every element which is related to that directive.

Comment: Could you please evolve that? I tried the same thing without a directive, plain on a <select> element - same behaviour. See here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LlUh3j35QQeFWhq73Kwm?p=preview

Comment: ok let see but can you tell me what is your requirement actually?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (have been travelling). I just want the trigger to be shot once, every time I change a value, just like I would assume an ng-change on a dropdown would work.